# Make flex item wrap to the next row with following items continuing the flow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the red box to be on the 2nd row, but then i want the divs that are defined after it, to continue on the first line, so that all the black boxes essentially wrap around the black box. Can this be achieved with flexbox?

It should look like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|         4         |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 8 | 9 |10 |11 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|12 |13 |
+---+---+
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='a'>1</div>
  <div class='a'>2</div>
  <div class='a'>3</div>
  <div class='b'>4</div>
  <div class='a'>5</div>
  <div class='a'>6</div>
  <div class='a'>7</div>
  <div class='a'>8</div>
  <div class='a'>9</div>
  <div class='a'>10</div>
  <div class='a'>11</div>
  <div class='a'>12</div>
  <div class='a'>13</div>
</div>
```

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqqeJN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have better luck using CSS grid for this task:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* this will make the elements to flow around*/
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  /*full width row*/
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='a'>1</div>
  <div class='a'>2</div>
  <div class='a'>3</div>
  <div class='b'>4</div>
  <div class='a'>5</div>
  <div class='a'>6</div>
  <div class='a'>7</div>
  <div class='a'>8</div>
  <div class='a'>9</div>
  <div class='a'>10</div>
  <div class='a'>11</div>
  <div class='a'>12</div>
  <div class='a'>13</div>
</div>
```

> dense
>
> If specified, the auto-placement algorithm uses a “dense” packing algorithm, which attempts **to fill in holes earlier in the grid if smaller items come up later**. This may cause items to appear out-of-order, when doing so would fill in holes left by larger items.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid-auto-flow)</sup>

Comment: I love this solution because it requires no weird javascripting to figure out what the order value for the inserted element must be. Since in the actual usecase the amount of columns isn't predetermined, I had to change it a little, but it works fine! See codepen for updates

Comment: Good thinking. This looks like the perfect use-case for `grid-auto-flow: dense`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `order` property along with the `nth-child()` pseudo-class.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.b {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.a:nth-child(1) { order: -5; }
.a:nth-child(2) { order: -4; }
.a:nth-child(3) { order: -3; }
.a:nth-child(5) { order: -2; }
.a:nth-child(6) { order: -1; }
/* the default value all items is 0 */

.container > div {
  height: 50px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='a'>1</div>
  <div class='a'>2</div>
  <div class='a'>3</div>
  <div class='b'>4</div>
  <div class='a'>5</div>
  <div class='a'>6</div>
  <div class='a'>7</div>
  <div class='a'>8</div>
  <div class='a'>9</div>
  <div class='a'>10</div>
  <div class='a'>11</div>
  <div class='a'>12</div>
  <div class='a'>13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was playing around with order just now too, and I think it's a way forward, but the position of the 'b' div is flexible, and if for example it appears as the 8th element, it should show beneath the 2nd row. Is there any easy way of making this flexible? Without having to calculate the row of each item to find the right one

Comment: Well, with those new details, flex is no longer an option. But CSS Grid can help with `grid-auto-flow: dense`, as outlined in a [newly posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55347046/3597276).